# App not running in Emulator after initializing app in void main

Tags: android, flutter, windows, dart

I following a tutorial on how to build a flutter instagram clone. I am on windows and i keep on encountering an asyn error while trying to run the app on emulator but it works on web.. any idea on how to solve this issue?

Here is the code..

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';


import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


import 'package:insta_leafy/responsive/mobile_screen_layout.dart';


import 'package:insta_leafy/responsive/responsive_layout_screen.dart';


import 'package:insta_leafy/responsive/web_screen_layout.dart';


import 'package:insta_leafy/utils/colors.dart';





void main() async {


  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();


  await Firebase.initializeApp();


  runApp(const MyApp());


}





class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {


  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);





  // This widget is the root of your application.


  @override


  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


    return MaterialApp(


      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,


      title: 'Instagram Clone',


      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(


        scaffoldBackgroundColor: mobileBackgroundColor,


      ),


      home: const ResponsiveLayout(


        mobileScreenLayout: MobileScreenLayout(),


        webScreenLayout: WebScreenLayout(),


      ),


    );


  }


}
```

Here is the error..

```
Restarted application in 1,115ms.


E/flutter ( 7202): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(null-error, Host platform returned null value for non-null return value., null, null)


E/flutter ( 7202): #0      FirebaseCoreHostApi.optionsFromResource (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/pigeon/messages.pigeon.dart:248:7)


E/flutter ( 7202): <asynchronous suspension>


E/flutter ( 7202): #1      MethodChannelFirebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:89:25)


E/flutter ( 7202): <asynchronous suspension>
```

I tried changing the minsdkversion to 21 and ensured that all my packages were compatible with my flutter version. I also enabled multiDexEnabled But i still encountered the error.

Comment: The error come from Firebase, you must check again the implementation of firebase is correct or not. Because the failed occur in line `await Firebase.initializeApp();`.

Comment: @ryandra Exactly, please make sure you've configured Firebase correctly and also add the `google-services.json` file in your `android/app` directory

Comment: Okay thanks for the feedback. Let me check it out again and reach out to you if it persists or works.

Comment: Soo update i looked into what you told me and i found out what i didnt do, apparently i didnt add options: in the await Firebase.initializeApp soo that it can get the apikey,appid,messenger id and project id. I found an article in medium that helped me out after further research. Here is the link https://medium.com/@zaidbinkhalid/resolving-firebase-configuration-error-in-flutter-a-step-by-step-guide-70c5a5a146da hope it helps